# Transferring large files with iOS Share Extension

Tags: ios, memory, share, limit

Our main app allows our users to post media (videos and images) as well as documents on the timeline with a file size limit of 500 megabytes on a timeline.

We're currently working on a Share Extension to allow users to share files throughout the OS to that timeline. However we're running into the issue that the Share Extension has a hard memory limit of 120 megabytes.

The current implementation in our main app requires that the files selected by the user get converted to a Data object before getting compressed and then uploaded to the API via multipart form data. However to achieve this we must load the files into memory where we run into the hard memory limit.

Apple documentation is very brief and there's not a lot to be found on SO or elsewhere on how to achieve this. There are some workarounds found by storing these files (or references) in UserDefaults and then opening the main app to handle them but that kind of defeats the purpose of sharing something quickly via the extension.

What would be a way around this limit to allow us to upload these large files?

Comment: I have the same question. Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Late to this question I ran into the same issue now. The issue is the memory limit imposed by Apple on File extensions, so you can not use a data object in memory if that object is more than around 50 - 100 MB. I changed the upload to an `NSURLSessionUploadTask` `uploadTaskWithRequest:fromFile:completionHandler:`, where I upload the file from the file system directly. If you can not change that you need to provide the multipart form data and boundaries in the delegate of `uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:` but consider that also here you can not read the whole file at once but have to stream it as well.